# Configure Router with Mac

Tags: macos, router

My router's IP address is `192.168.1.245`. I tried to access it but without success, because my WIFI address is `10.0.1.10` and my Ethernet address (via the Thunderbolt port) is `169.254.xxx.xxx`.

How can I configure my router without having internal IP addresses?

Comment: How do you know your router's IP address if you can't connect to it?

Comment: Because I once configured it so on a Windows PC.

Comment: Where does your Mac get the IP address from? If the router acts as a DNS server the Mac should pick up a "proper" address automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Settings - Network - Thunderbold Ethernet - Configure IPv4: Manually: 192.168.1.20. After this I am able to access the router.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have changed the service order to place the Wi-Fi connection (which looks like it would have worked) above the self-assigned address. This sort of thing usually is a temporary issue unless your router has access controls based on MAC addresses which would explain why it wouldn't issue an IP address to a new network endpoint.